# Starting docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-dynamodb

I have a **docker-compose.yml** file that starts two services: **amazon/dynamodb-local** on 8000 port and **django-service**. django-service runs tests that are dependent on dynamodb-local.

Here is working docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  dynamodb-local:
    image: "amazon/dynamodb-local:latest"
    container_name: dynamodb-local
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  django-service:
    depends_on:
      - dynamodb-local
    image: django-service
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    env_file:
      - envs/tests.env
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command: sh -c 'cd /app && pytest tests/integration/ -vv'
```

Now I need to run this without docker-compose, only using docker itself. 
 I try to do following:

```
docker network create -d bridge net // create a network for dynamodb-local and django-service
docker run --network=net --rm -p 8000:8000 -d amazon/dynamodb-local:latest // run cont. att. to network
docker run --network=net --rm --env-file ./envs/tests.env -v `pwd`:/app django-service /bin/sh -c 'env && cd /app && pytest tests/integration -vv'
```

I can see that both services start, but I can't connect to the dynamo-db.

Where is the problem? Any comment or help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through the `docker-compose.yml`, the `amazon/dynamodb-local` container has a name defined (`container_name: dynamodb-local`, If we do not set this property, `docker-compose` will use the service's name as container name). This enables other containers in the same network to address the container through its name.

In the `docker-run` command, we do not set an explicit container name. We can set an explicit container name by executing `docker run ... --name dynamodb-local ...`. More details can be found in the corresponding [`docker run` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#name---name).